# Installed plasma-desktop along side of ubuntu 18.04 and fonts are not correct

Tags: gnome, fonts, plasma-5

I went to try out the plasma-desktop along side of gnome.  I noticed some issues, so I went back to gnome and deleted plasma-desktop.  Now my fonts seem pretty off.  Does anyone know how to restore the fonts back to the ubuntu gnome defaults?  I'm on ubuntu 18.04.  Some fonts are correct, and some are off.